# Storing user-contributed text with links and formatting

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, user-input

How can I store user contributed text while maintaing links, formatting, etc? (Basically exactly what stack overflow does with our posts)

It seems extremely dangerous to allow any HTML to be stored in text. What are some existing conventions?

Site is built in PHP, databases are MySQL if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and other sites such as [Github](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/), extend [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

Here is a [PHP port](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/) of Markdown. You could use it for display and store the raw Markdown formatted input.

Comment: Nothing, I saw you editing the post and thought you couldn't decide on the comma placement in the first sentence. Anyways, your answer is great thank you. I'll accept it once we're at the 10 minute requirement.

Comment: Caught me mid edit. No worries. See if you get other answers. I prefer Markdown, and it is used by the sites you referenced.

Comment: It seems that Markdown requires you to be built on top of WP, or some other things I'm not super familiar with (e.g. smartypants). Is there a particular one of these which is pretty unobtrusive? My site is pretty custom built and I don't think I want an installation of WP to handle the comments.

Comment: Markdown has nothing to do with any of the technologies you mentioned. The port on Github is one file. It may support those platforms, but is not dependent on them.

Comment: Apparently I can't read today. I guess it supports WP and other things. This is awesome, thanks!